# "col-xxl" is adding a padding in fluid-container bootstrap

Tags: html, css, css-grid, padding, bootstrap-5

i've been experimenting with the bootstrap grid system, than i encountred this issue with the "col-xxl" class, can you advise on why this happened and how to overcome this?

```
 <style>
    [class*="col"] {
      padding: 1rem;
      background-color: #33b5e5;
      border: 2px solid #fff;
      color: #fff;
    }
  </style>
<div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert">
    A simple primary alert—check it out!
  </div>
<div class="container-fluid text-center ">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xxl">col1-xxl</div>
            <div class="col-xxl">col2-xxl</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl">col1-xl</div>
        <div class="col-xl">col2-xl</div>
    </div><div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg">col1-lg</div>
        <div class="col-lg">col2-lg</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md">col1-md</div>
        <div class="col-md">col2-md</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm">col1-sm</div>
        <div class="col-sm">col2-sm</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the code i worked on

Answer (score 0):

You had an additional `row` class wrapped around your `div(s)`. Additionally, you forgot to wrap a `row` class around your `col-xl`. See code snippet below:

```css
[class*="col"] {
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #33b5e5;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid text-center ">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xxl">col1-xxl</div>
        <div class="col-xxl">col2-xxl</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl">col1-xl</div>
        <div class="col-xl">col2-xl</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg">col1-lg</div>
        <div class="col-lg">col2-lg</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md">col1-md</div>
        <div class="col-md">col2-md</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm">col1-sm</div>
        <div class="col-sm">col2-sm</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you, a rookie mistake

Comment: Hi @Noah314 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72880323) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You have placed class `row` 2 times which at `col-xxl` and the same is missing above `col-xl`..
please refer snippet and code for your reference..
also I've attached snap for details..

```css
[class*="col"] { padding: 1rem; background-color: #33b5e5; border: 2px solid #fff; color: #fff; }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    
        <div class="alert alert-primary text-center" role="alert">
        A simple primary alert—check it out!
      </div>
        <div class="container-fluid text-center ">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xxl">col1-xxl</div>
                <div class="col-xxl">col2-xxl</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xl">col1-xl</div>
                <div class="col-xl">col2-xl</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg">col1-lg</div>
                <div class="col-lg">col2-lg</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md">col1-md</div>
                <div class="col-md">col2-md</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm">col1-sm</div>
                <div class="col-sm">col2-sm</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

[image: Reference Snap]

Thanks..